# Tool to detect String.isEmpty calls in Android/Java source code?

Tags: android, software-development, command-line

`String.isEmpty` was not implemented at the time of Android 2.1.

Not knowing this, new contributors often commit code that contains `String.isEmpty` calls, and we only notice the problem when crash reports start flowing.

Is there a tool that can detect `String.isEmpty` calls in an Android project.
We will integrate this tool in our release bash script.

Requirements:

- Command-line
- Free, ideally open source
- Skips `Collection.isEmpty` and `TextUtils.isEmpty` calls, which are OK.

Answer (score 2):

[Lint](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/lint.html) can do that:

First make sure that your `AndroidManifest.xml` contains `android:minSdkVersion="7"` or lower, so that Lint knows `String.isEmpty` should not be used.

Then just run `lint . --nowarn`

---

If you get other unneeded check errors, just create a `lint.xml` file to filter them out like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<lint>
    <issue id="MissingTranslation" severity="warning" />
    <issue id="MissingQuantity" severity="warning" />
</lint>
```

And run `lint . --config lint.xml --nowarn`